# Penalty kick after time expires - should the referee play rebounds on for longer?

Tags: rules, football, officiating, penalty-shot

It is well known that a soccer referee should allow any team to play a penalty even if a period of play has ended.

Should the referee allow the team who has the penalty to continue the penalty kick rebound, or, should they blow the final whistle soon after the penalty is taken, since there is no time remaining?

Comment: I think the point you're trying to get at is the wording change in the current laws. It used to state that the kick is completed when the referee decides it is over, but now has the wording as provided in [Nij's answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/14465/3526). On first reading, it appears that rebounds are now allowed, but I'm sure this is simply editorial oversight and players are still not allowed a follow-up from a rebound (as this would also apply to kicks from the penalty mark aka shootouts as well).

Comment: What time are we talking about exactly?

Comment: @Don_Biglia - this question is about the a penalty kick that is taken after time has expired. If a referee awards a penalty kick with seconds left, and chooses to not add more time, the penalty kick still must be taken. However, the match is over when it is complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Law 7.4, from the [IFAB Laws of the Game](http://www.theifab.com/#!/laws/the-duration-of-the-match/chapters/penalty-kick), states

> If a penalty kick has to be taken or retaken, the half is extended until the penalty kick is completed.

Thus, the referee should blow the whistle to end play *when the kick is completed*.

Law 14.1, [from the same source](http://www.theifab.com/#!/laws/the-penalty-kick/chapters/penalty-kick-procedure), states

> The penalty kick is completed when the ball stops moving, goes out of play or the referee stops play for any infringement of the Laws.

This definition is reasonably straightforward: the game should continue *despite time expiring* until such a point as one of the above conditions is met.

Additional documents are intended for officials and the management of situations of special importance where the appropriate and lawful procedure or action may not be clear. However, while it does discuss various points around the taking of penalties and of timekeeping, this is not an area where further clarification is made.

Therefore, by a strict reading of the law as written, **play continues until it naturally stops**.

Comment: I tend to believe this was simply editorial oversight, and referees will not be allowing players a follow-up kick. Such a massive change would surely have been discussed further as the other major changes have been. I have sought clarification from other refereeing organisations on this matter and will post as answer as soon as I know how this will be interpreted.

Comment: @studro I'm not so sure. This revision seems to be very much the IFAB modernising the outlook of the laws, compared to the very traditional FIFA formulation. Since time is "lost" for the penalty to be set up, it makes sense to "regain" some time for the last play of the game immediately after the penalty is taken. Thus, play would continue as described above, and end-of-time signalled either once the ball is dead or stopped while live, or (as in existing practise with corners) when sufficiently far away from the penalty box.

Comment: In most social or recreational competitions, there is no added time, as it makes scheduling too different. In these competitions, referees are expected to call full time as soon as time is up, even if the ball is in the penalty area. Obviously time is extended for a penalty kick to be taken, but no time is added for the setup, meaning it is effectively up once the kick is complete. In your corner kick example, the referee would not wait until the ball has left the area in such a competition.

Comment: In a professional competition, this clause is irrelevant, as any smart referee will use their discretion to "find time" to avoid any possible disputes over time.

Comment: An official *shouldn't* wait until it's left the box *at any level*, but as you say, those who may be more liable to, and therefore want to avoid inciting controversy will ignore their watch because "I forgot to include the time for that last sub" (whether or not any subs occurred at all, being moot).

Comment: I think the perfect example that illustrates this answer, and the question in general, is the [Watford vs Leicester Championship Play-off 12/13](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7AeHvFNMaBI), where Leicester were awarded a penalty in the fifth minute of added time (4 minutes were given by the officials), for the Watford goalkeeper to make a double save. Play then continued, Watford broke on the counter-attack and scored at the other end, winning the game.

Comment: @ImClarky while interesting to know of, that match occurred under different Laws, and being a real-world case, there are other factors that may have meant the "bonus time for PK" Law didn't apply (for example: official time rarely matches up with what is shown by broadcasters, or even with the indicated time by the fourth official).

Comment: @Nij You keep saying that the rules on the penalty kick have changed. Have they? Can you show me the old rule?

Comment: @rathony https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/footballdevelopment/refereeing/81/42/36/log2013en_neutral.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiFj7aGgsTOAhVJqJQKHeaRDuAQFgggMAI&usg=AFQjCNGG46OOFa8RQCJVdFIDfz60ODhPCg. Page 45, is the relevant part of the old Laws. The final words are extremely different to the current Laws.

Comment: @Nij What's the real difference between **the referee stops play for any infringement of the Laws** (NEW LAWS) and **the referee decides when a penalty kick has been completed** (OLD LAWS)? I don't see any difference, but the rephrasing of the previous Laws.

Comment: @rathony Old Law: the referee decides when the kick is completed, is literal. They can blow the whistle whenever they want after the player kicks the ball, even before it's reached the goal or goalkeeper. New Law: the referee does not have that ability. They must only blow the whistle when the game allows it. This is not a rephrasing, the implications for a match are very different.

Comment: @Nij The referee can blow the whistle whenever he wants if there is any infringement of the Laws now. What makes you think the referee can't blow the whistle whenever he wants now? I mean, I really can't understand your logic. What are the implications? Can you show me one specific scenario where the Laws are different?

Comment: The referee can't just blow the whistle when he feels like it. There has to actually be an infringement! This very question and all of this discussion is the specific scenario where the Laws are different. You're trying to answer as if it's somehow all the same, which again, is not the case.

Comment: @Nij There was no stoppage time added in the Olympics quarter final match  between Korea and  Honduras even if one Honduras player was lying for three minutes from 43 minutes to 46 minutes (until one minute has passed since the start of the stoppage time), but the referee blew the whistle exactly at the end of 3-minute stoppage time. What makes you think a referee can't just blow the whistle when he feels like it? That's what he did in that match. Has he violated the new Laws? I mean, if you could show me one scenario that can explain the changed Laws, we would not have this long discussion

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but I just realized the current version of Law 10 actually uses the same words to describe when a kick from the penalty mark is over: *'The kick is completed when the ball stops moving, goes out of play or the referee stops play for any infringement of the Laws'* (http://theifab.com/#!/laws/determining-the-outcome-of-a-match/chapters/kicks-from-the-penalty-mark). Does it mean that follow-up kicks are now allowed during KFTPM as well? That would be crazy.

Comment: I'm going to have to -1 this, because in spite of what the Law says, in practice, referees will still be declaring that the penalty kick is completed if after the kick, a player other than the goalkeeper touches it (whether at a penalty at the end of a period or at kicks from the penalty mark ie. a shootout). This is not explicitly written, but this is a convention that has always been followed, and always will be until the Laws or a circular from IFAB explicitly say otherwise.

Comment: @studro Yes, I agree with you: that quote from Law 10 actually proves that a second kick is not allowed when a penalty is awarded at the end of a match, because the same thing is not permitted during KFTPM (it's always been like this), and there's no way the same sentence could change its meaning from Law to Law. The wording is still pretty bad though, as it lacks any reference to other players other than the goalkeeper touching the ball.

Comment: Whether referees think it should be written, or will apply it, another way, that is what the law actually says now.

Comment: That's true, but the question wasn't strictly about what is written - it was: "Should the referee allow the team who has the penalty to continue the penalty kick rebound ..."

Comment: And as far as I can tell, the answer to that is "no".

Answer (score 2):

[Law 14 - The Penalty Kick, Section 1 - Procedure](http://theifab.com/#!/laws/the-penalty-kick/chapters/penalty-kick-procedure) states:

> The penalty kick is completed when the ball stops moving, goes out of play or the referee stops play for any offence.
>
> Additional time is allowed for a penalty kick to be taken and completed at the end of each half of the match or extra time. When additional time is allowed, the penalty kick is completed when, after the kick has been taken, the ball stops moving, goes out of play, is played by any player (including the kicker) other than the defending goalkeeper, or the referee stops play for an offence by the kicker or the kicker’s team. If a defending team player (including the goalkeeper) commits an offence and the penalty is missed/saved, the penalty is retaken.

Therefore, the kicking team is not allowed a follow-up; as soon as anyone other than the goalkeeper touches the ball after the kick is taken (provided they do not commit an offence in doing so), the period of play is over.

Answer (score -2):

Law 14 - (Penalty Kicks/Extended Time) states:
"....At the end of the half or at the end of the game, **time will be extended to take** (or retake if necessary) a penalty kick. When a penalty kick has been legally taken or retaken at the end of either half or during a tie-breaking procedure, **play is over as soon as a goal is scored** (directly, or indirectly off the goalkeeper, the goal post, the crossbar, or any combination thereof); ***when any player other than the defending goalkeeper touches the ball***; or when the referee has decided that a goal has not been scored."

I think this law clearly prohibit the action of scoring rebounded balls. by covering this scenario implicitly in the following line: *"..when any player other than the defending goalkeeper touches the ball.."*

Comment: You've provided a quote, but no source for this quote.

Comment: The quote has been taken from BAYS website: https://www.bays.org/node/33

Comment: That's not an authoritative source, as BAYS appear to use a modified version of the Laws of the Game: ["Excerpted from The Laws of the Game, as established by the International Football Association Board (IFAB), with modifications by US Youth Soccer, Mass. Youth Soccer, and BAYS."](https://www.bays.org/node/20)